# How pass input field value using route parameter to a controller in laravel

Tags: laravel

How can i pass an input field value using route parameter to my controller. i want to pass the value of the input field below to my controller after clicking the anchor tag below, How can i achieve that?

My code below

```
 <input type="text"  name="sender_address" value="Alberta" class="form-control margin-bottom-20 hide" style="border:1px solid  brown;" placeholder=" Enter & Save address">

 <a href="/sender_address/{sender_address}">Save Address</a>
```

Comment: Don't pass big data with GET param

Comment: Why not use a form for it?

Comment: I didn't use form because the input field is inside another form, and it's not possible for me to nest forms

Answer (score 3):

it's not recommended way to achieve that requirement, as an alternative you can pass the values to controller via a **AJAX POST** method with the help of **jquery**.

```
 <input type="text" id="sender_address" name="sender_address" value="Alberta" class="form-control margin-bottom-20 hide" style="border:1px solid  brown;" placeholder=" Enter & Save address">
 <a class="save_address">Save Address</a>
```

I've added class to your anchor tag. and let's continue

```
$('.save_address').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var address = $('#sender_address').val();
   
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/sender_address',
        data: {
            sender_address : address
        },
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but after clicking the save address anchor tag, there was no any response. And i have a jquery script link like this "<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>" . What am i doing wrong?

Comment: did you add class name as 'save_address' to your anchor tag?

Comment: Yes i did, exactly as you did yours

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below 3 option to pass an input value

1)you can use Form

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="path_to_action" method="POST">
      @csrf
    <input type="text"  name="sender_address" value="Alberta" class="form-control margin-bottom-20 hide" style="border:1px solid  brown;" placeholder=" Enter & Save address">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-add btn-lg">Save Address</button>    
</form>
```

2)You can use jQuery / AjAX to do that.

```
<input type="text" id="sender_address" name="sender_address" value="Alberta" class="form-control margin-bottom-20 hide" style="border:1px solid  brown;" placeholder=" Enter & Save address">
 <a class="save_address">Save Address</a>
$('#save_address').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var address = $('#sender_address').val();
   
   $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/sender_address',
        data: {
            sender_address : address
        },
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

3)You can use the `<a>` tag

```
<a href="{{ route('sender_address', $sender->id) }}"></a>
```

If you use `<a href="{{ route('sender_address', $sender->id) }}"></a>` you need to retrieve data from database using that ID

Comment: Thank you for your help. I didn't use form because the input field is inside another form, and it's not possible for me to nest forms. I don't understand your 3rd option for passing input value, can you please break it down for me to understand the code.

Comment: See this video just like the EDIT option. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dg5iB_ehUhQ&ab_channel=FundaOfWebIT